# ASP.NET Web API: How to use multiple HttpClientCredentialTypes for authentication in selfhosted szenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have a selfhosted ASP.NET Web API server (HttpSelfHostServer) running under .NET 4.0.
In the HttpSelfHostConfiguration I can set **one** ClientCredentialType, for example to HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm.

I would like the server to accept **several** credentialtypes, for example Basic, NTLM and Certificate. The client should be able to authenticate with any of these credentialtypes.

Is this possible?